framer-motion parallax effect on items in list
I am trying to get a parallax effect on each item in my list.
I have created a sandbox here enter link description here
Basically , theres a text containing component and a large coloured box each taking up 50% of the width or a flexbox row. The ordering is dependent on the index of the component in the list created by mapping over an array.
When scrolling down, I'd like the contents on the left to move down and stop at the end of its container. As the next row comes into view , that should do the same.
Right now , as you can see from my sandbox, although I try and not update the transition Y value until the component is in view , the contents of the left hand side move anyway and so drop below the right hand contents.
Could someone tell me ho to limit the movement of the contents left hand side of each ro until that row is in the viewport.
Unfortunately I am using framer-motion version 4, so I do not appear to have useScroll ,  so I might be out of luck.
